# Lead Acid Battery Charge C/20Ah

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid, ampere-hour

I need to charge a lead acid battery, I will be manually developing a program to set the current. Its the "US 12V XC2" Deep Cycle battery. Here is a link to the datasheet: http://usbattery.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/usb_12V_data_sheet_2015_web.pdf

The part I am confused about is "Bulk Charge Constant current @~10% of C/20 Ah in amps" does that mean C = 92? or C = 155? or is C/20Ah = 155?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1C is the equivalent current per hour of the capacity of the battery. So if you have a 10Ah battery, 1C is 10A. C/20 for your battery is therefore \${155\text{A} \over 20} = 7.75\text{A}\$.

Answer (score 0):

usbattery.com uses a non standard terminology, they use C/20 instead of C20 (or shorter C) that is the battery capacity when is discharged in 20 hours, in the example 155 Ah. According to that

"Bulk Charge Constant current @~10% of C/20 Ah in amps"

means

Bulk Charge Constant current = C/10 A, in the example 155/10=15.5 A

15.5 A is in perfectly in line with the required 12 hours for recharging a fully discharged battery. If you use C/20=7.75 A, recharging will last more than 20 hours...